# Should I install virtualenv with sudo or not?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have installed `pip` and `pip3` with `sudo` in my machine. I am new to python and its entire world of virtual environments, hence I am not sure if I should install `virtualenv` with `sudo` or not. `virtualenv`'s [website](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) isn't clear about it. It states says: `[sudo] pip install virtualenv`, as if it was optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `sudo` if you are installing virtualenv into a system Python and your current account can't write into the `site-packages` directory for that Python install.

You can test with `pip -V` or with `python -m site` to see where the `python` binary looks for packages, and look for the `.../site-packages` directory. If you can't write in that directory with your current account, you need `sudo`.

You can also use `pip install --user virtualenv` to install it only for your own account even with a system-installed Python setup. The `virtualenv` script is then installed into `~/.local/bin`, make sure to include that path into your `PATH` environment variable, or just use `python -m virtualenv` as the command-line tool alternative.